# Is there a way to set the radius of an edge loop exactly by typing in a number somewhere?

Tags: modeling, edges, scale

New to blender. I am trying to adjust the radius (or diameter) of various edge loops on a cylinder. I know that I can do this via selecting the edge loop and using keyboard shortcut <kbd>S</kbd>. But is there a way to display the radius of an edge loop in a toolbar so I can just punch in a number and have it be the exact radius or diameter that I want?

Comment: After pressing `S`, you can type in a percent value of the scale size you want; for example, `.5` for halving the scale, and `2` for doubling the scale.

Answer (score 1):

If know the current diameter of the loop, you can scale the whole loop by `x/d`, where `x` is your new diameter, and `d` is your current one.

To determine the current diameter, you can use the `Measure` tool in the 3D viewport. Set the snapping mode to `Vertex` and Click+drag between two vertices on opposite sides of the loop. (It appears that even with snapping enabled, you still have to hold the `Ctrl` key to snap with the `Measure` tool.)

[image: measure tool]

Once you know the current diameter of the loop, select the whole loop and scale by `x/d`.

For instance, if you want the final diameter to be 6.5, and your current diameter is 3.60979 (as in the example above), you can scale the loop by `6.5/3.60979`, or `1.80066`. Press `S` to scale, and type the value.

**Note:** Because of the way Blender parses math during operations, you may not be able to type `6.5/3.60979` during the operation. You either have to calculate the value beforehand and type the one number (`1.80066`), **or** you can scale twice, once by `6.5` and once by `1/3.60979`.